# Primefaces (5.1) - column resize by shifting the remaining columns

Tags: primefaces

Primefaces, version 5.1.
Please tell, is there any possibility to change column width without reducing the width of the next column, but by shifting the rest of the columns.

Explanation:

1. There are resizible columns.
2. When doing resize of the first column - the width of the second changes.
3. BUT, need to move other columns without reducing the width of the second column  (the width of second and other columns do not change and also scrolling should appears after increase the width of the column).

Please, help if you know how to resolve this problem

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same problem. As far as I have investigated, the root of the problem is in method "resize()" in PrimeFaces' source datatable.js at line 2123 ( [here](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/primefaces/trunk/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/datatable/datatable.js#2123) ).

If you have a look at PrimeFaces Showcase, resizable columns ([datatable - resize](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/columnResize.xhtml)), you will be able to get this method in e.g. Chrome Browser Console with `PrimeFaces.widgets.widget_form_cars2.resize;`

Armed with this knowledge, we can try to replace this method with our own resize, which would not change `nextColumnHeader`, `nextColumn` and `nextColumnFooter`.

E.g., execute the following code on the ([PrimeFaces Showcase page](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/columnResize.xhtml)) and play with the second table.

```js
PrimeFaces.widgets.widget_form_cars2.resize = function(event, ui) {
  var columnHeader;
  var change = null;
  var newWidth = null;

  if (this.hasColumnGroup) {
    var groupResizer = this.findGroupResizer(ui);
    columnHeader = groupResizer.parent();
  } else {
    columnHeader = ui.helper.parent();
  }

  if (this.cfg.liveResize) {
    change = columnHeader.outerWidth() - (event.pageX - columnHeader.offset().left);
    newWidth = (columnHeader.width() - change);
  } else {
    change = (ui.position.left - ui.originalPosition.left);
    newWidth = (columnHeader.width() + change);
  }

  if (newWidth > 15) {
    columnHeader.width(newWidth);
    var colIndex = columnHeader.index();

    if (this.cfg.scrollable) {
      this.theadClone
        .find(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId(columnHeader.attr('id') + '_clone'))
        .width(newWidth);
      if (this.footerCols.length > 0) {
        var footerCol = this.footerCols.eq(colIndex);
        footerCol.width(newWidth);
      }
    }
  }
}
```